# Stored procedure call from Access VBA interrupted with "Run the RECONFIGURE statement to install"

Tags: sql-server-2005, ms-access, vba, ado

I have an Access ADP tied to an SQL Server 2005 backend. I'm trying to implement a stored procedure to update our clients' addresses, which requires me to execute a program from the command line using `xp_cmdshell`. The procedure works fine from SSMS, but when I call it from Access VBA, via an ADO Connection object, it produces the following "error":

> Run-time error '-2147217900' (80040e14): Configuration option 'show
>   advanced options' changed from 0 to 1. Run the RECONFIGURE statement
>   to install.

It's not really an error -- it's a standard message SQL Server produces when executing `sp_configure`. The stored procedure does call `RECONFIGURE`, but for some reason Access interprets the message as an error.

Any idea how I can get this to stop?

For what it's worth, here's some of the code I'm using. This is a stored procedure to enable/disable `xp_cmdshell`:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spEnableXpCmdShell]
    (@enabled bit)
WITH EXECUTE AS 'NKA\jrosenberg'
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON

    EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
    RECONFIGURE

    EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', @enabled
    RECONFIGURE

    EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 0
    RECONFIGURE
```

That's called from my main sp, which is rather long, like so:

```
EXEC [dbo].[spEnableXpCmdShell] 1
```

Finally, here's a somewhat abridged version of the offending VBA code:

```
Public Function DoNCOA(con, Optional caseId = Null, _
                                 Optional docId = Null) As Integer

    'Call the NCOAProces stored procedure asynchronously.
    'Returned integer is not success or failure, but position in the queue

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command, _
        prm As ADODB.Parameter

    With cmd
        .ActiveConnection = con
        .CommandText = "spNCOAProcess"
        .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
        .CommandTimeout = 1800 
        Set prm = .CreateParameter("CaseID", adInteger, adParamInput, , caseId)
        .Parameters.Append prm
        Set prm = .CreateParameter("DocID", adInteger, adParamInput, , docId)
        .Parameters.Append prm
        .Execute Options:=adAsyncExecute, adExecuteNoRecords
    End With

    [...That's all the important stuff]

End Function
```

Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

How about running sp_configure within try/catch block so no message is returned to the client?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976(v=sql.90).aspx